# Azure Function in South UK timeout when communicating with service bus in West US

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an premium Azure Service Bus running in the West US region. Multiple websites and functions use the service bus and things are running pretty smoothly. Except for an Azure Function I have hosted in South UK. It produces timeout errors in the log, not daily, but maybe weekly looking like this:

```cs
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: UptimeChecker
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusTimeoutException: The operation did not complete within the allocated time 00:00:59.9999875 for object message.Reference: 0bc5a54a9dd14d67b64a1a35f0e1bae3_G11, 8/25/2020 10:01:08 AM
 ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation did not complete within the allocated time 00:00:59.9999875 for object message.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.SendingAmqpLink.EndSendMessage(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.OnSendAsync(IList`1 messageList)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.OnSendAsync(IList`1 messageList)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.SendAsync(IList`1 messageList)
```

I'm surprised why this is happening from South UK. I have other functions running in Europe and also in the Australian data center. So what could cause South UK to timeout?

Comment: is there a chance that traffic from UK region is blocked ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't. Like stated, this happens from time to time. Most of the time, the function is running like it should. The weird thing is that I only see these timeouts on this function app and not on any of the other ones. I can understand that service bus can have downtime (even on premium). But that should affect the other regions too that runs in the same intervals.

Comment: can you deploy this function in another region and test if similar issue occurs ? if not then it may be more of an application issue than azure issue..

Comment: Yep. I have the same function app deployed in 5 regions currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer to my own question to give some kind of explanation to people visiting the original question. I didn't found out why the timeouts were there. But everything went back to normal after re-creating the function. I had a range of other problems with other consumption-based functions. All of the apps were created a couple of years ago. Go check the app service plan name of your function. If it contains the region (ex: WestUSPlan) you should re-create the function app and deploy it again. New names will be ASP-*.